# Contenteditable div, copy/paste html gives white spaces SAF/Chrome

Tags: webkit, contenteditable

I got a contenteditable div with some text eg. "test abc", when I select "test" by double clicking it, then copy it.
After that I move my cursor between "b" & "c", then paste my copy value.

In Safari/Chrome my result is this: 
"test ab test c"

And it should be like this: 
"test abtestc"

Answer (score 0):

It seems webkit prefers that your editable content be **surrounded** in a tag. I tried with a div and a p and it starts behaving as intended

[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvFNL/1/)